# Binary search for an array of strings

Tags: java, search, binary

I am wondering why my binary search is returning a different value than my linear search is. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Should I be returning something different?

```
public class BinarySearch extends SearchAlgorithm
{
    public int search (String [] words, String wordToFind) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    int lowIndex = 0;
    int highIndex = words.length - 1;
    while (lowIndex <= highIndex) {
        int midIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;
        if ((words[midIndex]).equals(wordToFind)) {
            return midIndex;
        }
        if (wordToFind.compareTo(words[midIndex]) > 0) { //wordToFind > midIndex
            lowIndex = midIndex + 1;
        }
        if (wordToFind.compareTo(words[midIndex]) < 0) { //wordToFind < midIndex
            highIndex = midIndex - 1;
        }
        lowIndex++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

Here is what it returns. The first group is with the linear search and the 2nd is with the binary.

```
DISCIPLINES found at index: 11780 taking 0 comparisons.
TRANSURANIUM found at index: 43920 taking 0 comparisons.
HEURISTICALLY found at index: 18385 taking 0 comparisons.
FOO found at index: -1 taking 0 comparisons.

DISCIPLINES found at index: 11780 taking 0 comparisons.
TRANSURANIUM found at index: 43920 taking 0 comparisons.
HEURISTICALLY found at index: -1 taking 0 comparisons.
FOO found at index: -1 taking 0 comparisons.
```

Comment: Which one is correct?

Comment: what are the contents of `words`? Your linear search says none of them found.

Comment: suggest using `.equals` instead of `==` for strings, also is the array sorted?

Comment: The top one is correct. "FOO" is not in the list of words. The linear search (top) is returning their position. It is a text file full of words.

Comment: It is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I just replaced == with .equals() and now everything is returning correctly except "heuristically" which is now returning -1?

Comment: Why do you have `lowIndex++;`? What do you expect this will do and why is it necessary?

Comment: When I didn't have lowIndex++ it created an infinite loop.

Comment: That's not how programming works. You don't throw stuff in at random to "see if it fixes things".  You must understand your algorithm and write the code correctly.  To see what's happening, step through the code one line at a time in your IDE debugger.

Comment: Please refer to the description of a binary search on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)  @nullpointer's answer has problems even though it might "work".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing your logic to :

```
int midIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;
while (lowIndex <= highIndex) {    
    if ((words[midIndex]).equals(wordToFind)) { //use equals
        return midIndex;
    }
    if (wordToFind.compareTo(words[midIndex]) > 0) { //wordToFind > midIndex
        lowIndex = midIndex + 1;
    }
    if (wordToFind.compareTo(words[midIndex]) < 0) { //wordToFind < midIndex
        highIndex = midIndex - 1;
    }
// getting rid of infinite loop when the value is not in the list
    if (lowIndex==highIndex && !wordToFind.compareTo(words[midIndex]) {
        return -1;
    }
    midIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2; // notice removing lowindex++
}
```

The `lowIndex++` inside the `while` was not required since that was updating the lowIndex irrespective of the BS algorithn updating the indexes based on the comparison with midIndex value.

Comment: Using `<=` in the while condition will result in infinite loop if the search word is not in the array.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Could you just briefly explain why/how?

Comment: @JimGarrison updated with a return for the infinite loop condition

Comment: This code is hacky and ugly.  A binary search does not require stuff like that.  Come on, the algorithm is given plainly on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) in a form that can be readily expressed in Java.

Comment: @Jim Garrison these are the requirements for my assignment and I appreciate nullpointer's suggestions even if they are "hacky and ugly".

Comment: @iloveprogramming never the less, please try and implement the algorithm shared by @ Jim, that shall help you learn better :)